# What is a cocartesian comonoid, and what is a cocartesian comonoidal functor?

Tags: haskell, applicative, category-theory, monoids, distributive

I've been experimenting with monoids and Distributives lately, and I think I've found something of interest (described in my answer) - are these already known structures? (I've been unable to find any reference to them online, and I don't *think* I've missed some reason they would be nonsensical)

If not previously known, do they seem useful, or interesting to anyone who isn't me?

The questions that lead me here are:

1. What happens if you swap products for sums in comonoids?
2. What happens if you swap products for sums in comonoidal functors (coapplicatives, coalternatives, codivisibles, codecidables)? (Only somewhat answered for the first two)

Answer (score 3):

The following is fairly light on the laws behind these structures, as they are a recent product of experimentation.

First, the cocartesian comagma, plus identity:

```
-- modified to an equivalent definition for clarity
class Semigroup a where
    (<>) :: (a,a) -> a
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
    mempty :: () -> a

class Split a where
    split :: a -> Either a a
class Idsplit a where
    void :: a -> Void
```

These are datatypes with an inherent ability to branch - to be a proper comonoid, this branching should not change its value (due to a neat typeclass instance for functions), but that leads to a far less interesting typeclass for the purposes described here.

Here's that instance for functions, corresponding to the monoid-requiring Divisible instance for Op:

```
instance Split r => Alt ((->) r) where
    (<!>) :: (r -> a) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> a)
    f1 <!> f2 = either f1 f2 . split
instance Idsplit r => Alternative ((->) r) where
    (<|>) = (<!>)
    empty = absurd . void
```

This will not be associative unless Split is lawful, unfortunately - but I think its non-associative form could still be of use?

It is also possible to define an Unfoldable typeclass, similar to Foldable for monoids, Foldable1 for semigroups, and their theoretical further family members:

```
class Unfoldable l where
    unfoldMap :: Split m => (m -> e) -> (m -> l e)
instance Unfoldable [] where
    unfoldMap strat root = case strat root of
        Left m -> []
        Right m -> m : unfoldMap strat root

newtype Unfolder a = Unfolder { getUnfolder :: (a, a -> Maybe a) }
instance Split (Unfolder a) where
    
unfoldr :: (a -> Maybe (e,a)) -> (a -> [e])
unfoldr strat root = unfoldMap
    (fst . fst . getUnfolder)
    (Unfolder ((undefined, root), (strat . snd)))
-- uses Unfolder (e,a) similar to Endo a in foldr
-- the undefined will be dropped by list's instance of Unfoldable, and so is safe
```

Next: what I think is a "cocartesian coalternative functor":

```
class Functor f => Match f where
    matchWith :: (c -> Either a b) -> f c -> Either (f a) (f b)
class Match f => Matchable f where
    voidWith :: (a -> Void) -> f a -> Void

-- Maybe is a Match, but not a Matchable due to Nothing
instance Match Maybe where
    matchWith _ Nothing = Left Nothing
    matchWith choose (Just a) = bimap Just Just $ choose a
-- this won't work
instance Matchable Maybe where
    voidWith void (Just a) = void a
    voidWith void Nothing = ?????

-- Pick always needs an a value, and so is Matchable as well
data Pick a = Pick1 a | Pick2 a
    deriving Functor
instance Match Pick where
    matchWith choose (Pick1 a) = bimap Pick1 Pick1 $ choose a
    matchWith choose (Pick2 a) = bimap Pick2 Pick2 $ choose a
instance Matchable Pick where
    voidWith void (Pick1 a) = void a
    voidWith void (Pick2 a) = void a
```

For algebraic datatypes, Match describes functors with at most one value in each constructor (which can then be observed and pattern-matched over).

Matchable describes functors with exactly one value in each constructor (so an uninhabited value leads to an uninhabited functor).

I believe Matchable is strictly weaker than a Traversable typeclass that traverses with Functors instead of Applicatives, but have not proven this - this would correspond to all Distributives being Applicative. (All algebraic datatypes with exactly one parameter value in each constructor are both Matchable and Traversable.)

```
class Functor l => FTraversable l where
    ftraverse :: Functor f => (a -> f b) -> (l a -> f (l b))

instance FTraversable f => Match f where
    matchWith choose fc = 
        let fab = fmap choose fc :: f (Either a b)
            afb = fsequence fab :: Either a (f b)
            bfa = fsequence (fmap swap fab) :: Either b (f a)
        in  case (afb, bfa) of
                (Left a, Right (f a)) -> Left (f a)
                (Right (f b), Left b) -> Right (f b)
                (_, _) -> undefined -- impossible?

instance FTraversable f => Matchable f where
    voidWith void fa = (absurd1 :: forall a. V1 a -> Void) . ftraverse ((absurd :: Void -> V1 ()) . void) $ fa

instance Matchable l => FTraversable l where
    ftraverse strat la = ???
```

Matchables seem interesting to me, being a part of the extended applicative family that I've been unable to find any reference to, but they really come into their own with Distributive functors from the 'distributive' library (the dual of Traversables).

Normal Distributives are isomorphic to `Reader r` for some r, and are famously (I presume famously, at least? It seems well known) equivalent to Representable functors, or right adjoints in Hask. Interpreted for algebraic datatypes, they are the algebraic datatypes with exactly one constructor.

These can be extended beyond the Functor-based Distribute, though!

```
-- all defined using cotraverse instead of distribute, for clarity
-- (which is equivalent to using distribute)

-- isomorphic to Reader r (f a) for some r and Matchable f, not sure which
-- for algebraic datatypes, those with a finite constructor count
class Functor l => MatchableDistributive l where
    cotraverseMatchable :: Matchable f => (f a -> b) -> (f (l a) -> l b)

-- isomorphic to Reader r (f a) for some r and Match f, not sure which
-- for algebraic datatypes, those with a finite non-zero constructor count
class MatchableDistributive l => MatchDistributive l where
    cotraverseMatch :: Match f => (f a -> b) -> (f (l a) -> l b)

-- isomorphic to Reader r a for some r ~ Rep l
-- for algebraic datatypes, those with exactly one constructor
class MatchDistributive l => Distributive l where
    cotraverse :: Functor f => (f a -> b) -> (f (l a) -> l b)
```

These mirror Traversable ~ `(l (), [a])`, Traversable1 ~ `(l (), NonEmpty a)`, and the much-rarer functor-traversable ~ `(l (), a)`.

(Of interest: for algebraic datatypes, the each Traversable family member has as many records as the Distributive equivalent has constructors, and vice versa)

(Of interest: just as Coapplicatives are trivial in Hask, so are Comatchables - I expect this can be interpreted as Coapplicatives enabling the many records of Distributive, and Comatchables enabling the many constructors of Traversable?)

Matchables also act like Applicatives for defining generic instances, except that while it's products of Applicatives that have a unique Applicative instance, it's actually sums of Matchables that have a unique instance!

Cocartesian Coapplicatives act as the Alternative equivalent - Cocartesian Coapply can be interpreted as being able to choose which side to take in an 'unzip' operation, and Cocartesian Coapplicative describes a totally uninhabited functor like V1 in generics.

```
class Functor f => Bias f where
    biasWith :: (c -> (a,b)) -> f c -> Either (f a) (f b)
class Bias f => Biasable f where
    devoidWith :: (a -> ()) -> (f a -> Void)

-- empty analogue
devoid :: Biasable f => f a -> Void
devoid = devoidWith (const ())

-- (<|>) analogue
biasing :: Bias f => f a -> Either (f a) (f a)
biasing = biasWith (\a -> (a,a))
```

In summary:

- There are 4 types of monoid family here (monoid, comonoid, cocartesian monoid, cocartesian comonoid), of which the first and last are non-trivial in Hask. Maybe there are 6 if you include These as well as (,) and Either?
- There are 6 members of the applicative family here (applicative, alternative, divisible, decidable, matchable, biasable), plus the trivial coapplicative and comatchable - this could presumably be filled out further to a total of 16 members! Or 36 including These as above
- Matchable functors enable weaker versions of Distributive - where Distributive's data is always present, the data in a Match-Distributive is only sometimes present, or potentially never present in a Matchable-Distributive

(These-wise applicative = Align from the 'semialign' package, but with fewer laws? corresponding to the relationship between applicatives and zips, seen in ZipList's typeclass instances?)

Edit: A more symmetric Unfoldable instance for lists

It is possible to leave the choice to bias left or right until after-the-fact, using a similar method to the Monofoldable typeclass.

```
class MonoUnfoldable l e | l -> e where
    unfoldMapMono :: Split m => (m -> e) -> (m -> l)
-- this will always create an infinite list
instance MonoUnfoldable [Either a a] (Either a a) where
    unfoldMapMono strat m = strat m : unfoldMapMono strat m

pickLefts, pickRights :: [Either a a] -> [a]
pickLefts (Left a : as) = a : pickLefts as
pickLefts _ = []
pickRights (Right a : as) = a : pickRights as
pickRights _ = []
```

However, useful instances of Split for unfolding will be value-changing, and will have already chosen a left/right bias for these value changes. For example:

```
instance Num n => Split (Sum n) where
    split (Sum n)
        | n > 0     = Right $ Sum (n-1)
        | otherwise = Left  $ Sum (n-1)

unfoldMap getSum (Sum 10) = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
```

As such, the asymmetry is practically inherent to the process, and all that is needed is to be consistent about whether Left or Right signal an end-point for listlike (linear, finite) unfolds.

Comment: Surely, at `void :: a -> Void` we should pause and ask whether all of this can make any sense at all – seeing as it will only be possible for uninhabited types?

Comment: As for `Unfoldable`, at least the `[]` instance seems ad hoc and weird that it behaves completely assymmetric in `Left` vs `Right`. (Which, yes, is common in Haskell, but only because we keep abusing `Either e` as an error monad.)

Comment: `void :: a -> Void` mirrors `mempty :: () -> a` - where `mempty` is demonstrating that the type is inhabited by providing an identity value, `void` is demonstrating that the type is uninhabited, which just happens to be a less useful identity than monoid's (though I believe it has the same uses the `Total` typeclass from the `total` library, used for pattern matching with prisms?)

Comment: The asymmetry of Unfoldable here is unfortunate, but asymmetry in such things is incredibly common - list's Alternative instances are asymmetric, its Applicative instance's ordering is asymmetric, every single sum type's Applicative and Alternative instances are asymmetric, and the asymmetry is extremely useful in this case - it would be more elegant if lists were free cocartesian comonoids instead of free(ish) monoids, though!

Comment: “which just happens to be a less useful identity” is an understatement. I agree that it still has its uses, but mostly just for proving that something involving this type doesn't actually _use_ it. Regarding symmetry: I don't mean _invariance_, very few instance have that and it would be kind of boring. What they do generally have is some sort of equivariance, e.g. `l <|> m ≡ reverse (reverse m<|>reverse l)`, i.e. a flip of the order can somehow be expressed in terms of bijective transformations. Your proposed instance seems very far from that, though perhaps you can demonstrate some analogue.

Comment: I have edited the post to add some thoughts on symmetry in list's unfoldable instance to the end - the greatest invariances I can think of here are, if there is some `newtype Switch a = Switch { getSwitch :: a }` newtype that switches Lefts and Rights in Split and Unfoldable instances: `unfoldMap m = getSwitch $ unfoldMap (Switch m)`, which really just amounts to "Either is symmetric", or `unfoldMap m ++ getSwitch (unfoldMap m) == getSwitch (unfoldMap (Switch m)) ++ unfoldMap (Switch m)`, which is saying that the underlying infinite sequence is unchanged by switching.

Comment: Hm. I'm still not very convinced of all this, but you certainly showed some interesting what-ifs.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer (which I ideally should have written some time before the first anniversary of the question, but alas), I will mostly stick to covariant monoidal functors in order to keep the scope manageable, though there will be opportunity to consider some of the other aspects of the question and of [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72553399/2751851).

Another editorial choice of mine will be exercising restraint in using "co-" to name things. That's not just because it's easy to get lost in a soup of prefixes when, as you note, there is a baseline of sixteen hypothetical monoidal functor classes, but also because for each of them there generally is more than one plausible candidate for the "co-" moniker. For instance, consider `Applicative` (cast into a by-the-book monoidal functor signatures):

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    zipped :: (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
    unit :: () -> f ()
    -- zipped = uncurry (liftA2 (,))
    -- unit = const (pure ())
```

One might want to adopt as "coapplicative" its straightforward [oplax monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oplax+monoidal+functor) counterpart, obtained by switching from Hask to Hask<sup>op</sup> (and thus turning around the arrows of the methods) while keeping `(,)` as the tensor product:

```
class Functor f => Unzip f where
    unzip :: f (a, b) -> (f a, f b)
    trivialU :: f () -> ()
```

These combinators have a lawful implementation for every `Functor`, with `unzip = fmap fst &&& fmap snd` and `trivialU = const ()`. Notably, this is the coapplicative alluded to by [the *distributive* documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Distributive.html) when it notes that:

> Due to the lack of non-trivial comonoids in Haskell, we can restrict ourselves to requiring a Functor rather than some Coapplicative class.

Besides the triviality of `Unzip`, another plausible objection to calling it coapplicative is that a thorough dualisation of applicative should also replace `(,)` (the product in Hask) with `Either` (the product in Hask<sup>op</sup>). Doing so leads to your `Matchable` class, which I'll display here in a presentation borrowed from [a post by Conor McBride](https://fplab.bitbucket.io/posts/2007-07-08-decisive-functors.html) :

```
class Functor f => Decisive f where
    orwell :: f (Either a b) -> Either (f a) (f b)
    nogood :: f Void -> Void
```

(It is worth noting that similar questions arise when switching from covariant to contravariant functors. While replacing `Functor` with `Contravariant` in the signatures of `Applicative` leads to `Divisible`, if the tensor products are also dualised in a compatible way we end up with `Decidable` instead. Furthermore, as argued in [my *Divisible and the monoidal quartet* blog post](https://duplode.github.io/posts/divisible-and-the-monoidal-quartet.html), `Decidable` mirrors `Applicative` more closely than `Divisible`.)

While at first it might look like only functors holding exactly one value can be `Decisive`, that only holds if we require `orwell` to be an isomorphism. In particular, as McBride highlights, any comonad (or really, any functor with something to play the role of `extract`) can be made `Decisive`:

```
orwellW :: Comonad w => w (Either a b) -> Either (w a) (w b)
orwellW u = case extract u of
    Left a -> Left $ either id (const a) <$> u
    Right b -> Right $ either (const b) id <$> u

nogoodW :: Comonad w => w Void -> Void
nogoodW = extract
```

`orwellW` uses the result of `extract` as a default value, in order to redact one of the `Either` cases. For demonstrative purposes, here is how it might be deployed in implementing a filter-resembling operation which, instead of merely removing rejected, replaces them with a default:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as N

redact :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
redact p d = N.tail . either id id . orwellW . (Right d :|) . map classify
    where
    classify a = if p a then Right a else Left a
```

```
ghci> redact (>= 0) 0 [5,-2,3,0,-1,4] 
[5,0,3,0,0,4]
```

In this implementation, `classify` uses the predicate to set up an `Either`-based cosemigroup (in other words, a lawful instance of your `Split`). `orwellW` lifts this cosemigroup to non-empty lists (assuming that, for the sake of consistency, `p d` is `True`).

(`redact`, by the way, also brings to mind how a padding zip can be implemented through a suitable `Applicative` instance for non-empty lists, as demonstrated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21350096/2751851), incidentally also written by McBride, though at the moment I'm not sure about how deep the relationship really is.)

On the connections between `Decisive`/`Matchable`, `Traversable` and `Distributive`, I believe they boil down to all functors holding exactly one value (the left adjoint Hask endofunctors, or your `FTraversable`) being comonads, and thus `Decisive`. As far as these are concerned, the less powerful distributive you propose would ultimately be just `FTraversable` (pushing a left adjoint inside, rather than pulling a right adjoint outside), and right now I don't see how it might generalise to `Decisive`.

---

Now let's look at `Alternative`. A by-the-book monoidal functor presentation might be:

```
class Functor f => Alternative f where
    combined :: (f a, f b) -> f (Either a b)
    nil :: () -> f Void
    -- combined = uncurry (<|>) . bimap (fmap Left) (fmap Right)
    -- nil = const empty
```

Since we'll need it in a little while, it's worth emphasising we can recover `(<|>)` by lifting [the trivial `Either`-based monoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56200814/2751851):

```
-- either id id :: Either a a -> a
aplus :: (f a, f a) -> f a
aplus = fmap (either id id) . combined
```

The straightforward oplax counterpart to `Alternative` happens to be something familiar:

```
class Functor f => Filterable f where
    partition :: f (Either a b) -> (f a, f b)
    trivialF :: f Void -> ()
```

This is actually equivalent to [the familiar, `mapMaybe`-based `Filterable` class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.4.2/docs/Witherable.html#t:Filterable), as covered in detail by [*Is every Alternative Monad Filterable?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60732274/2751851). In particular, using the predicate cosemigroup lifting illustrated before with `redact` leads directly to `filter`.

We haven't dualised the tensors yet, though. Doing so leads to your `Bias` (and `Biasable`, but I'm giving up on the identity in order to have inhabited types):

```
class Functor f => Bias f where
    biased :: f (a, b) -> Either (f a) (f b)
```

Lifting the trivial `(,)`-based comonoid gives us:

```
biasing :: f a -> Either (f a) (f a)
biasing = biased . fmap (id &&& id)
```

`Bias` offers, at least, a classifier of shapes (whether `biasing` gives out `Left` or `Right` depends on the functorial shape of its argument), plus an associated choice between pair components. I say "at least" because dropping the identity leaves `Bias` with just an associativity law, and said law doesn't rule out changes or rearrangements of the `f`-shape, as long as they are idempotent and preserve the `Left`/`Right` classification.

If `Bias` being so light on laws is deemed a problem, there is one plausible way of tightening it up somewhat. In order to present it, let's go back to `Applicative` and `Alternative` for a moment. While in the monoidal functor formulation `Alternative` is in principle independent from `Applicative`, there are a few other possible laws that are sometimes invoked to connect the two classes and better delineate the meaning of `Alternative` (for commentary on that, see [Antal Spector-Zabusky's answer to *Confused by the meaning of the 'Alternative' type class and its relationship to other type classes*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081604/2751851)). One of these laws is right distributivity of `(<*>)` over `(<|>)`:

```
(u <|> v) <*> w = (u <*> w) <|> (v <*> w)
```

We can translate that to the vocabulary we're using here...

```
zipped (aplus (u, v), w) = aplus (zipped (u, w), zipped (v w)
```

... and make it pointfree, for the sake of easier manipulation:

```
zipped . first aplus = aplus . bimap zipped zipped . distribR

distribR :: (((a, b), c) -> ((a, c), (b, c))
distribR ((a, b), c) = ((a, c), (b, c))
```

Now, if `Bias` is dual to [`Alt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-6.0.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Alt.html) (`Alternative` sans identity) and `Decisive` is dual to `Applicative`, we should be able to dualise the distributivity law for a functor which is both `Decisive` and `Bias`:

```
first biasing . orwell = codistribR . bimap orwell orwell . biasing

codistribR :: Either (Either a c) (Either b c) -> Either (Either a b) c
codistribR = \case
    Left (Left a) -> Left (Left a)
    Left (Right c) -> Right c
    Right (Left b) -> Left (Right b)
    Right (Right c) -> Right c
```

Adopting this law (and/or the analogous left distributivity law) would forbid `biasing` (and, by extension, `biased`) from changing the shape. That's because, by the identity laws of `Decisive`, `orwell` can't change shapes, which means, in particular:

```
first biasing (orwell (Right <$> u)) = Right u
```

Applying the distributive law then leads to:

```
codistribR (bimap orwell orwell (biasing (Right <$> u)) = Right u
```

Which is only possible if `biasing` leaves the shape untouched. The distributivity law, therefore, can ensure `biased` is a shape classifier with bundled with a choice between `fmap fst` and `fmap snd`. That it all works out so neatly highlights the correspondence not just between `Alternative`/`Alt` and `Bias`, but also between `Applicative` and `Decisive`.