# Is this "Coapplicative" class a superclass for Comonad?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, comonad

Recall the `Applicative` class:

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

    liftA2 h x y = fmap h x <*> y
    (<*>) = liftA2 id
```

Though it's not immediately clear how to express this class in terms of (mathematical) category theory, it becomes clear when the following function is defined:

```
liftZ2 :: Applicative f => (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
liftZ2 (x, y) = liftA2 (,) x y
```

Here, `(,)` should be identifiable as the categorical product. Replacing products by coproducts and reversing all the arrows gives the following class:

```
class Functor f => Coapplicative f where
    copure :: f a -> a
    coliftZ2 :: f (Either a b) -> Either (f a) (f b)
```

Some instances:

```
import Data.Functor.Identity
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NonEmpty
import Data.Either

instance Coapplicative Identity where
    copure (Identity x) = x
    coliftZ2 (Identity (Left x)) = Left (Identity x)
    coliftZ2 (Identity (Right y)) = Right (Identity y)

instance Coapplicative NonEmpty.NonEmpty where
    copure (x NonEmpty.:| _) = x
    coliftZ2 (Left x NonEmpty.:| xs) = Left (x NonEmpty.:| lefts xs)
    coliftZ2 (Right y NonEmpty.:| ys) = Right (y NonEmpty.:| rights ys)

instance Coapplicative ((,) e) where
    copure (_, x) = x
    coliftZ2 (e, Left x) = Left (e, x)
    coliftZ2 (e, Right y) = Right (e, y)

instance Monoid m => Coapplicative ((->) m) where
    copure f = f mempty
    coliftZ2 f = case copure f of
        Left x -> Left (fromLeft x . f)
        Right y -> Right (fromRight y . f)
```

I have a strong intuition that `Coapplicative` is a superclass for `Comonad`, but I don't know how to prove it. Also, is there a `Coapplicative` instance that is not a `Comonad`?

Comment: Related https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/is-there-a-concept-of-something-like-co-applicative-functors-sitting-between-com

Comment: I have looked at that class in the first part of [my answer to *What is a cocartesian comonoid, and what is a cocartesian comonoidal functor?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76452269/2751851).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer, but I can at least make the case that your instance of `Coapplicative NonEmpty` cannot be derived from `Comonad` methods alone; that is, if there is some parametric implementation of

```
coliftZ2 :: (Comonad w) => w (Either a b) -> Either (w a) (w b)
```

then it does not generate your instance for `NonEmpty`.  This is because the methods of `Comonad NonEmpty` alone do not afford us any way of changing the length of a list, but your `NonEmpty` instance of `coliftZ2` changes the length.   So if `NonEmpty` is to be a `Coapplicative`, it must do so in some other way, or else `Coapplicative` can't be a superclass of `Comonad`.

---

As you investigate further, I would say it is worth exploring the comonad

```
data Two a = Two a a
    deriving (Functor)

instance Comonad Two where
    extract (Two x _) = x
    duplicate (Two x y) = Two (Two x y) (Two y x)
```

and considering what its `coliftZ2` implementation must be.  You haven't given any laws for `Coapplicative`, but if you did, I would put my money on this breaking them because there is no implementation of `coliftZ2` which is satisfyingly symmetrical.  Both of the following equations are rather forced, but they seem to indicate very different intentions for the operation:

```
coliftZ2 (Two (Left x) (Left y)) = Left (Two x y)
coliftZ2 (Two (Left x) (Right _)) = Left (Two x x)
```

In my opinion the question that will shed the most light on this is: What should we expect of the *relationship* of `coliftZ2` to the comonad methods?